# Using curl to make ajax call

Tags: jquery, rest, curl, superagent

```
curl -X DELETE https://www.filestackapi.com/api/file/**HANDLE**?key=APIKEY
```

I want to use the above curl call to delete a file from filestack storage. How can I use that in an ajax call either using jQuery or SuperAgent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.filestackapi.com/api/file/HANDLE?key=APIKEY',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

With superagent

```
request
  .del('https://www.filestackapi.com/api/file/HANDLE?key=APIKEY')
  .end(function(err, res){

  });
```